# iOS: How to hide status bar after dismissing modal VC that need status bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller that displays full screen, and from the view controller another modal VC can be presented, the modal VC requires status bar, but after dismissing the modal VC controller, the base VC has the space for status bar on top, and even I set:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]
```

the status bar is hidden but the space is still there, and I checked the frame of the view of the base VC, it starts from 0, I don't think I should make its y-coordinate starts from -20, but what else can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
```

From the docs on applicationFrame:

> This property contains the screen bounds minus the area occupied by
>   the status bar, if it is visible. Using this property is the
>   recommended way to retrieve your application’s initial window size.
>   The rectangle is specified in points.

For a more robust solution, change your frame in response to a status bar frame change.  Your application delegate subclass can implement:

```
-application:willChangeStatusBarFrame:
-application:didChangeStatusBarFrame:
```

Or, you can register for these notifications using NSNotificationCenter:

- UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
- UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your method, but it did not work for me, I solved it in this way, when the modal VC dismisses, in the `viewDidAppear` of base VC I need to:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
[self.view layoutSubviews];
```

I know this is not a good solution, but it is the only thing I could think of at the moment, thanks anyway for your help.